# Is it possible to declare 2 static mutable variables depending on each other?

Tags: rust

I am trying to declare two static mutable variables but I have a [error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7816e51f4d89b8dd7dfaf06cfc9d2ec1):

```
static mut I: i64 = 5;
static mut J: i64 = I + 3;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        println!("I: {}, J: {}", I, J);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0133]: use of mutable static is unsafe and requires unsafe function or block
 --> src/main.rs:2:21
  |
2 | static mut J: i64 = I + 3;
  |                     ^ use of mutable static
  |
  = note: mutable statics can be mutated by multiple threads: aliasing violations or data races will cause undefined behavior
```

Is it impossible? I also tried to [put an `unsafe` block on the declaration](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=35f17a4a04480667618ead85103fc852) but it seems to be incorrect grammar:

```
static mut I: i64 = 5;

unsafe {
    static mut J: i64 = I + 3;
}
```

Comment: Not sure about your usecase, but this is a bad idea to do so, unless you really know what you do.

Comment: Global, static, mutable variables are pure evil! Use `lazy_static!`, RefCell or a Mutex, if you really have to, but I would avoid them at all cost!

Comment: @hellow Oh, guys, of course I know that, I was just curious whether I can do so or not, because, you know, when I saw that I could not do this even with `unsafe` block, I was stuck. I haven't had a real use case for this by now, but I wanted to know whether it was possible in general or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is.

In your case, just remove `mut`, because static globals are safe to access, because they cannot be changed and therefore do not suffer from all the bad attributes, like unsynchronized access.

```
static I: i64 = 5;
static J: i64 = I + 3;

fn main() {
    println!("I: {}, J: {}", I, J);
}
```

---

If you want them to be mutable, you can use `unsafe` where you access the unsafe variable (in this case `I`).

```
static mut I: i64 = 5;
static mut J: i64 = unsafe { I } + 3;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        println!("I: {}, J: {}", I, J);
    }
}
```